# TypeError: lemmatize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word (WordNetLemmatizer)

Tags: nlp, nltk, lemmatization

I am facing a problem with WordNetLemmatizer.
What I am doing is filtering out useless words like int and int + str by using CountVectorizer.

Without further ado. My code is following:

> letters_only is a function to give me Fales if a word contains int, or int + str

```
groups = fetch_20newsgroups()
cleaned = []
all_names = set(names.words())

for post in groups:
  cleaned.append(''.join([lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower())
  for word in post.split()
  if letters_only(word)
  and word not in all_names]))
```

Just in case, I tried this as well:

```
for post in groups.data:
  for word in post.split():
    if letters_only(word) and word not in all_names:
      cleaned.append(''.join(lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()))
```

Two separate codes give me the same error which is "TypeError: lemmatize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully certain, because you didn't include the piece of code where `lemmatizer` was initialised, but I think this is the error you're experiencing:

```py
from nltk import WordNetLemmatizer

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer
word = "Arguments"
print(lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()))
```

Which outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\...\nltk_70755449.py", line 11, in <module>       
    print(lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()))
TypeError: lemmatize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'
```

As you can see from the [WordNetLemmatizer documentation](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.wordnet.html?highlight=wordnetlemmatizer#nltk.stem.wordnet.WordNetLemmatizer), you must *initialize* the class `WordNetLemmatizer`, and then call the class method `lemmatize` on that. Right now, `lemmatizer` is just a reference to the class `WordNetLemmatizer`, instead of an *instance* of this class. Luckily, this is an easy fix, as we can initialize this class with `WordNetLemmatizer()`:

```py
from nltk import WordNetLemmatizer

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer() # <- Notice the class initialization with ()
word = "Arguments"
print(lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()))
```

This outputs:

```
argument
```

That should solve your problem.